# Can a sentence be ended with two dots?

Tags: abbreviations

Consider a sentence that ends with a dotted abbreviation, like `inc.`.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation#Lowercase_letters), the sentence should end with a single dot, but I did not find a more formal reference to that rule.

Should the sentence be ended with one dot or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, no. One dot is the generally accepted rule. Like I've never come across a sentence with two dots.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall ever having seen a sentence end with and abbreviation stop followed by a full stop. Personally I would try to rephrase the sentence to make sure the abbreviation would not be the last word of the sentence.

Though it is not easy with some abbreviations like, for example, etc.

But then it would usually be clear from context that the sentence has finished. It's more of a problem where that is less obvious; you want to try and avoid ambiguities.

Answer (score 2):

Style guides usually say that the second dot, the sentence-ending full stop, isn't needed after an abbreviation that ends with the same symbol. The following capital letter is further indication of the end of the sentence. It becomes trickier when you want to end the sentence with a question or exclamation mark. Then it is common to keep both punctuation marks, but it's not unknown to drop the one at the end of the abbreviation, so long as it can't be confused with a different word.